# Displaying markers on Google Map with the help of several longitude' and latitude's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to display several placemarkers on the map with the help of lat's and long's that I have in my controller. There are no build errors and I am also able to see the map with the various placemarker but only the last info window is responding to the click event.

```
@section Script {   

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

}
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 875px; height: 600px">  
</div>  ` 

<script type="text/javascript">  
      //display the map                      

      var stockholm = new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002);  
        var myOptions = {  
                 zoom: 4, 
                center: stockholm,  
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
            };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);  
     //display markers   
     @foreach (var item in Model)  
     {  
    <text>  
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng('@(item.Latitude)', '@(item.Longitude)');  
      var title = '@(item.Title)';  
      var contentString = '<h3>' + title + '</h3>' 


       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latLng,
             map: map
    });


    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    </text>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: We really need a lot more context than what you've provided. Please consider editing so someone who isn't at all familiar with your problem can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

For each item in the model you are creating a marker. However the code to add the event listener to the marker (for the click ) is outside of the loop.

The event listener is only being added to the last marker, not every marker.